# TCP output stream error

Tags: ios, cocoa, tcp, stream, outputstream

I'm getting troubles with tcp outputstream (json). It happens that the server receive my stream splitted in two pieces. But it has to be in just one.

Thats my code for send the stream:

```
- (void) sendMessage:(NSDictionary *)message {
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    NSDictionary *dic=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"52731255-7b3d-5027-9937-ca311e61c14e",@"token",@"add",@"action",message,@"data",@"contact",@"element", nil];
    NSLog(@"send message: %@",dic);
    NSError *writeError = nil;
    [NSJSONSerialization writeJSONObject:dic toStream:outputStream options:0 error:&writeError];
}
```

But that's what the server receives:

```
Incoming data:"{"
Incoming data:"\"action\":\"add\",\"data\":{\"lastName\":\"Guilherme\",\"firstName\":\"Fabio\",\"entryId\":3,\"webLink\":\"www.test.com\"},\"element\":\"contact\",\"token\":\"s3e4-7b3d-fasd-afds-fadsfdsa123\"}"
```

This happens in some cases, but on another cases the Incoming data, becomes in one piece.

Comment: That's just how TCP works. The server needs to be able to handle it.

Comment: And its suposed to work like that? So in the server we have to make some kind of buffering process? Please help me, because I'm on this thing for one week already :S

The server is suposed to receive a simple json file :S

Comment: Yes. You'll need to have a way of detecting the end of a valid JSON value. You might also want to limit the maximum size of an object to avoid a DOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to fix this, that we found, is to send a symbol in the end of the stream message. Like "/r/n" and the server closes the message when he sees it. So it just process one message at a time.